# How to compare two different comma separated string values and check if ANY of the values from a different comma separated string exists in the first

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I hope I can explain this well. If something is not clear, please ask

I have a query to retrieve data for a User where he/she has access to to certain entities.

Basically in my user table there is a column where the user can have one or multiple comma separate integers. Here are some examples of what it will look like:

TABLE #1

```
User #1 value: ,1,
User #2 value: ,1,3,5,12,
User #3 value: ,12,
User #4 value: ,14,3,5, 
User #5 value: ,14,
```

My seconds table is has a very similar field.
If I have a records in my second table similar to this:

TABLE #2

```
User #1 value: ,3,
User #2 value: ,3,
User #3 value: ,3,
User #4 value: ,10,
User #5 value: ,11,5,12,
User #6 value: ,5,12,
```

So what I am trying to achieve is to take for instance User #2 value from TABLE #1 and I want to get all Users in TABLE #2 where any of their values is contained within Users #2 values.
Because User #2 has ,1,3,5,12, I should get result from TABLE #2 as follows:

```
User #1 
User #2
User #3
User #5 
User #6
```

I am currently using the following:

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM TABLE2 a
WHERE
CharIndex(','+convert(varchar,a.Agency)+',',(Select Agency from TABLE1 where UserID = 123)) > 0
```

This does not seem to be producing the results I am looking for.
This will work great if there is only 1 value from TABLE #1 for example ,3, but not multiple values.

Comment: Fix that and use tables with a row for each number and user instead of the string lists.

Comment: Please read about *data normalization*, this is a great example of consequences of a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query to get expected result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name
FROM TABLE2 a,
     dbo.Split((SELECT Agency
                  FROM TABLE1
                  WHERE UserID = 2),',') AS b
WHERE a.Agency LIKE '%,'+b.Slit_Func_ColumnName+',%'
```

Use `SPLIT` function.